# Should I use "such that," "so that," or "in a way that"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to edit a user guide in which the word *such* is used frequently  to describe the way things have to be done. For example:

> Step 1: Position the frame on the cone using the sliding bar, *such that*/*so that*/*in a way that* the cursor of the meter is on the crosshairs.

Or

> Step 4: Position the lens *such that*/*so that*/*in a way that* the lower segment marking is on the measuring dial.

Which usage correct? Should I use a different phrase?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about doing something or asking others to do a thing a certain way, the adverb **SO** should be used;

*'Position the frame on the cone using the sliding bar so that the cursor of the meter is on the crosshairs'*

**SUCH** is a determiner used mainly to add optional emphasis to a noun or noun phrase;
*'she has pretty eyes', 'she has such pretty eyes'*

(Both words have many more meanings and uses which can be studied at leisure)
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/such

You can ofcourse, use **SUCH** in your instructions if you really want to;

*'Position the lens in such a way so that the lower segment marking is on the measuring dial.'*

A very basic rule-of-thumb is, *'**SO** do something'* and *'**SUCH** emphasis'*

Answer (score 0):

*So that* and *such that* are synonymous in this context.  However, *such* is more formal, and commonly appears in mathematics (e.g. "The set of all prime numbers *p* such that *p*+2 is also prime"), while *so* is less formal and more likely to appear in (say) a DIY instruction manual.

Avoid "in a way that"; it's wordy and feels clumsy to me.

Comment: I always thought of *so that* as dynamic, and *such that* as static. The set of prime numbers doesn't change, so you should use *such that*, while if you're positioning something, you're moving it around, so you should use *so that*. I have no idea whether this is a real distinction. But [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=position+it+so+that%2Cposition+it+such+that+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cposition%20it%20so%20that%3B%2Cc0) seems to endorse *so that* here.

Comment: @Peter: "The building was architected such that the light from the window just touched the opposite wall at 3:00 PM" - that's dynamic, so is it wrong?

Comment: the building isn't currently in the process of changing, so there's an argument that it's still static in this use. I don't perceive it as wrong.  But if you said *"design the window such that the light from it touches the opposite wall at 3:00 PM"*, that sounds wrong to me.

Comment: I suspect it would sound better in the past tense, and even more so in the perfect.  That makes the dynamic into a static.  It also makes the writing slightly more formal, supporting either interpretation.